# How to make layer of different color mask on a image or a div element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, svelte, sveltekit

[image: here the red green and other colors on the brain image are layers of mask which means that the dead cells and defects are]
here the red green and other colors on the brain image are layers of mask which means that the dead cells and difected are different. Since it is a demo image but in real images, this kind of color will not appear so how can I add this kind of mask? You can see on the side of Canva has some selection tools that are used to remove if the doctor wants to remove the mask by dragging on specific mask areas. Images are in .raw format but no problem in frontend I will get in any format that I need. I loaded the image on a div element which is absolute and on this image I used HTML5 canvas for drawing for selection. but My Q is:
Which image format is useful to make this kind of masking task and how can I place the color of the mask and remove it by selecting drag on the mask in a specific area

My Q is:
Which image format is useful to make this kind of masking task and how can I place the color of the mask and remove it by selecting drag on the mask in specific areas? I am developing this software by SvelteKit but if the solution is available for React or vanilla javascript no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVG.
You can draw every shape you want with SVG.
You can manipulate every part of the image shape in SVG with JS.
You can use state to manage the selection system based on shape part click for example.